# Exponential distribution (probability of exact number)

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-process

Suppose the life of a computer can be modeled with an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$=(1/10) aka, .1 computers crash per year. How would I find the probability that exactly 14 crashes will occur in a month?

---

So, I think that lambda = $\frac1{120}$ crashes per month and I think I need to find 
Pr(X=14). Based on [the top answer from this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536497/what-is-the-difference-between-a-poisson-and-an-exponential-distribution), I think  I'm calculating:

$$
P_{14}(t) = \frac{(\frac1{120} *1)^{14}}{14!} e^{\frac1{120} *1}$$

(since t = 1 month, assuming there are 30 days in a month)

But I'm not quite sure that I'm doing this correctly.

Comment: The *number of crashes* is not exponentially distributed. I think you are trying to say that the *time* between crashes is exponential *or* the *number* of crashes per fixed time models a Poisson distribution. Note that both of those statements are equivalent.

Comment: I updated it to mean the computer's lifetime.

Comment: It looks right to me.

Comment: I guess I'm kind of confused when to use that equation and when to use the (exp(-lambda)*lambda^x) / x! equation. 

Tell me if I'm wrong, but let's say that I want to compare the probability of no computer crashes in a year vs month. For this, I used the second equation and got exp^(-1/10) and exp(-1/120) for year/month.

Comment: @nodel It is correct as well.